# MySQL: Number of subsequent occurrences

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table with four columns: id, from, to, msg.

The rows can look like this:

```
1 - foo - bar - hello
2 - foo - bar - zup?
3 - bar - foo - hi
4 - bar - foo - going okay
5 - bar - foo - you?
```

Now I wanna know how many times "bar" has tried to "talk" to "foo" without response. Like I wanna count the number of occurrences since "foo" was on the sending end.

In this example, before the next entry, it should return 3.

Is this possible in pure (My)SQL?

I'm using php on the server side.

Thanks for any tips and advice! =)

Comment: What do you mean "without response"? How many bar -> foo records there has been since the last foo -> bar

Comment: This is just like a conversation, right? In the example above bar has "talked" three times without "response" from "foo".

Comment: What is your rule for without response?
I am guessing in this case its 3?

Comment: "This is just like a conversation, right?" --- right, that is why you can create one more entity `conversation` with replies counter there ;-)

Comment: @tHeSiD: i think it is just a number of consecutive messages from `bar`, if he was the last person in the conversation. In current case it is bar and 3 not replied messages. If `foo` will response with `6 - foo - bar - blabla` then for `bar` not replied messages count will be `0`, and for `foo` it will be `1`.

Comment: The rule for no response doesn't matter, it should return the count anyways.

Comment: @Michael Grons: why don't you just follow to common practice with `read/unread`?

Comment: "The rule for no response doesn't matter" --- what is the question then? How to count? With `COUNT()` obviously.

Comment: What's so hard to get? I just wanna count how many times "bar" has written something to "foo" without any replay from "foo". That is not equal to just COUNT() obv.

Comment: @Michael Grons: it is not hard, believe me, I even described the same 5 comments ago, but after you replied that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, it's not like I needed an explanation to my own question.

Comment: @Michael Grons: you don't, but you need to explain clearly everything in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go.

It assumes a table name of **convo** and the **id** is autoincrementing.

This is just the mysql but the PHP calls can be added quite cleanly if you wrapped it in a function that passes in the from and to variables.

```
SELECT 
  count(*) AS unreplied
FROM
  `convo`
WHERE
  `convo`.`from` = 'bar' AND
  `convo`.`to` = 'foo' AND
  `convo`.`id` > (SELECT
                    id
                  FROM
                    `convo`
                  WHERE
                    `convo`.`from` = 'foo' AND
                    `convo`.`to` = 'bar'
                  ORDER BY
                    `convo`.`id` DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: @zerkms: Instead of trying to write the most comments, why not just answer the question? If the solution is "so obvious".

Comment: @Michael Grons: actually I've wrote almost the same query, but since Josh answered faster than me in about half of minute - I've deleted mine.

Comment: "Hmmm... did you test it?" --- is something wrong with it? It looks good.

Comment: @Michael Grons: Yea, works fine over here.  Here's a sql dump to re-create test db.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `convo`;

CREATE TABLE `convo` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `convo` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `convo` (`id`,`from`,`to`,`msg`)
VALUES
 (1,'foo','bar','hello'),
 (2,'foo','bar','zup'),
 (3,'bar','foo','hi'),
 (4,'bar','foo','going okay'),
 (5,'bar','foo','you'),
 (6,'foo','bar','leave me alone'),
 (7,'bar','foo','why'),
 (8,'bar','foo','dont you like me');

UNLOCK TABLES;

Comment: @Michael Grons: it counts the number of rows **after** the last `foo-bar` message occured. Clarify "didn't work". Is there a syntax error?

Comment: @Zerkms: are you bored or something? Stop stealing other users answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var1 = select id from table where fromname = "user1" and toname = "user2" order by id desc limit 1
var2 = select id from table where fromname = "user2" and toname = "user1" order by id desc limit 1

return var2-var1;
```

Comment: my syntax is off but i guess you get the idea.
Basically I am selecting the last ID of of conversation between 2 users and then subtracting it to get the numbe

Comment: you should **NEVER** rely your business logic on surrogate primary key. I even repeat it: **NEVER**.

Comment: I agree with zerkms. But the answer is close. If you can use the id as a starting point and then count the number of records with an id greater than that last reply, which also matches the same conversation "to" and "from".

Comment: @Josh Pinter: yep, I just mentioned that you should not rely on values, but you definitely can rely on order (as well as you can do the same with date field).

Comment: yes, but this was a quick fix, this whole problem can be avoided if he had a date field in it. but he didnt and this was the closest i could get

Answer (score -1):

$sql = "SELECT `fieldone` FROM `table` WHERE `fieldone` = 'foo'";

$results = mysql_query($sql);

$FooSendNumber = mysql_num_rows($results);

or

$FooSendNumber = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));

Oh wait, you want to see pure MySQL too.

Yeah, it's possible:

$sql = "SELECT MYSQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `fieldone` FROM `table` WHERE `fieldone` = 'foo';SELECT FOUND_ROWS();"

Should work.

Oh wait, crap, I see, you wanted the number of times without response.

Comment: @Phoenix: it is **really terrible** solution, since it is a special `COUNT()` function to do the same.

Comment: Incorrect: this will give the totalt count for the whole table.

Comment: @Michael Grons: since you did not give any criteria how to count - this answer cannot be incorrect. -1 to you.

Comment: It will return an integer of the number of rows found where fieldone = foo, i.e. where foo sent a message (2 in his table), replace foo with bar and you get the number of times bar has sent a message (3 in his table).

Comment: Hmmm.. what is "MYSQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS"?

Comment: Sorry, should be SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.  It allows you to use SELECT FOUND_ROWS();  But it's not what you need.